# Confusing with hashchange event and $stateChangeStart in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, hashchange

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState  , toParams, fromState, fromParams) 
    {

            if(toState.params.isRestricted === true && !$rootScope.isAppLog ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            // here I want value returned by the detectBackOrForward() onhashchange that exwcutes on back or forward button click
    });

    var detectBackOrForward = function(onBack, onForward) {
      hashHistory = [window.location.hash];
      historyLength = window.history.length;

      return function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash, length = window.history.length;
        if (hashHistory.length && historyLength == length) {
          if (hashHistory[hashHistory.length - 2] == hash) {
            hashHistory = hashHistory.slice(0, -1);
            onBack();
          } else {
            hashHistory.push(hash);
            onForward();
          }
        } else {
          hashHistory.push(hash);
          historyLength = length;
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("hashchange", detectBackOrForward(
      function() { return  "back" },
      function() { return  "forward" }
    ));
```

In the above code I successfully returned `"back"` and `"forward"` values when I clicked on **browser backward** and **forward buttons** respectively. But I am unable to use the returned value in `$stateChangeStart` event. Please help me to solve this.